# How to speed up calculation

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I have a function with two variables `f[x,y]` which gives me a matrix which isn't square. The matrix consists of 117 values divided in 17 rows of which the first 16 have 7 entries and the 17th has 5 entries. Now I want to summate the rows together which would give me a list of 17 values. I'm using `Plus @@ f[x,y]` which is working pretty fast, no problems yet. Then I want to use `g[x,y]`, where "M" is a 17x17 matrix:

```
 h[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ][r_?NumericQ]:= 
 Re[4/r^2 (-((x y^3 (1 + Log[y]))/10000) + (
       x y^3 (y/(r + y) + Log[r + y]))/10000) + 
    4 (-((x y^3 (y/(r + y) - Log[r] + Log[r + y] - (
           I y Log[-((2 I (r^4 + r^3 y))/(
              y (r + y) Sqrt[r^2 - y^2]))])/Sqrt[
           r^2 - y^2]))/(10000 r^2)) + 
       1/(10000 r^2)
         x y^3 (Sqrt[-r^2 + Rmax^2]/(Rmax + y) + y/(
          Rmax + y) - Log[Rmax + Sqrt[-r^2 + Rmax^2]] + 
          Log[Rmax + y] - (
          I y Log[(
            2 (r^2 Sqrt[-r^2 + Rmax^2] - (I (r^4 + r^2 Rmax y))/
               Sqrt[r^2 - y^2]))/(y (Rmax + y))])/Sqrt[
          r^2 - y^2]))] /. {Rmax -> 10^10000}



 lst1 = {{3.15355, 4.44045, 6.2525, 7.00804, 8.80402, 9.14525, 
  9.86788}, {11.0603, 12.3968, 12.8772, 13.3763, 13.8948, 15.5738, 
  16.8043}, {17.4556, 18.1322, 18.8349, 19.5649, 21.1109, 21.9291, 
  22.779}, {23.6619, 24.5789, 25.5315, 26.5211, 27.549, 28.6167, 
  29.7258}, {30.8779, 32.0747, 33.3178, 34.6091, 35.9505, 37.3438, 
  38.7912}, {40.2946, 41.8563, 43.4786, 45.1637, 46.9141, 48.7324, 
  50.6211}, {52.5831, 54.621, 56.738, 58.937, 61.2213, 63.5941, 
  66.0588}, {68.6191, 71.2786, 74.0411, 76.9108, 79.8917, 82.9881, 
  86.2045}, {89.5455, 93.0161, 96.6211, 100.366, 104.256, 108.297, 
  112.494}, {116.854, 121.383, 126.087, 130.974, 136.05, 141.323, 
  146.801}, {152.49, 158.4, 164.539, 170.917, 177.541, 184.422, 
  191.57}, {198.994, 206.707, 214.718, 223.04, 231.685, 240.664, 
  249.992}, {259.681, 269.745, 280.2, 291.06, 302.341, 314.058, 
  326.231}, {338.874, 352.008, 365.651, 379.823, 394.544, 409.835, 
  425.72}, {442.219, 459.359, 477.162, 495.656, 514.866, 534.821, 
  555.549}, {577.081, 599.447, 622.68, 646.814, 671.883, 697.923, 
  724.973}, {753.071, 782.258, 812.576, 844.07, 876.783}};



f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 Table[h[x, y][lst1[[i]][[k]]], {i, 1, 
   17}, {k, 1, Length[lst1[[i]]]}]



  M = {{1.01832, 0.502526, 0.290111, 0.177706, 0.106459, 0.0579574, 
  0.0292962, 0.0129835, 0.00504834, 0.00169406, 
  0.000545767, -0.000495994, -0.00486869, -0.00646868, -0.00593057, \
-0.0047329, -0.0026243}, {0.502526, 0.267132, 0.164875, 0.107666, 
  0.0692605, 0.0418384, 0.0238418, 0.0122081, 0.00521763, 
  0.0010883, -0.00113127, -0.00249909, -0.0054067, -0.00638845, \
-0.00578386, -0.00465564, -0.00261327}, {0.290111, 0.164875, 0.108312,
   0.0751867, 0.0518114, 0.0343914, 0.0216161, 0.0122918, 0.00569756, 
  0.00107588, -0.00179333, -0.00347203, -0.00583321, -0.00656596, \
-0.00591743, -0.00478729, -0.00270357}, {0.177706, 0.107666, 
  0.0751867, 0.0555428, 0.0410857, 0.029882, 0.0204477, 0.0126171, 
  0.00623702, 
  0.00122609, -0.00214038, -0.0041068, -0.00622814, -0.00682574, \
-0.00613324, -0.00497431, -0.00281743}, {0.106459, 0.0692605, 
  0.0518114, 0.0410857, 0.0328647, 0.026203, 0.0193351, 0.012735, 
  0.006619, 
  0.00139304, -0.00230435, -0.00448359, -0.00645938, -0.00696631, \
-0.00624759, -0.00507381, -0.00287797}, {0.0579574, 0.0418384, 
  0.0343914, 0.029882, 0.026203, 0.0229858, 0.018145, 0.0125942, 
  0.00680074, 
  0.00151599, -0.00235719, -0.00465484, -0.00651717, -0.00695649, \
-0.00622976, -0.00506182, -0.00287265}, {0.0292962, 0.0238418, 
  0.0216161, 0.0204477, 0.0193351, 0.018145, 0.0149695, 0.0107367, 
  0.00594676, 
  0.00139972, -0.00201082, -0.00405633, -0.00562187, -0.00597645, \
-0.00534831, -0.00434474, -0.00246484}, {0.0129835, 0.0122081, 
  0.0122918, 0.0126171, 0.012735, 0.0125942, 0.0107367, 0.00789289, 
  0.00446548, 
  0.0011148, -0.00144877, -0.00300594, -0.00415298, -0.00440819, \
-0.00394177, -0.00319905, -0.00181285}, {0.00504834, 0.00521763, 
  0.00569756, 0.00623702, 0.006619, 0.00680074, 0.00594676, 
  0.00446548, 0.00258697, 
  0.000703934, -0.000768727, -0.00167746, -0.00233435, -0.0024844, \
-0.00222045, -0.00179844, -0.00101669}, {0.00169406, 0.0010883, 
  0.00107588, 0.00122609, 0.00139304, 0.00151599, 0.00139972, 
  0.0011148, 0.000703934, 
  0.000263499, -0.000110751, -0.000357266, -0.000528968, \
-0.000576321, -0.000515071, -0.00041328, -0.000230905}, {0.000545767, \
-0.00113127, -0.00179333, -0.00214038, -0.00230435, -0.00235719, \
-0.00201082, -0.00144877, -0.000768727, -0.000110751, 0.000381429, 
  0.000672344, 0.000858107, 0.000883861, 0.000787505, 0.000642681, 
  0.000366993}, {-0.000495994, -0.00249909, -0.00347203, -0.0041068, \
-0.00448359, -0.00465484, -0.00405633, -0.00300594, -0.00167746, \
-0.000357266, 0.000672344, 0.00133432, 0.00174475, 0.00180766, 
  0.00160707, 0.00130422, 
  0.000740219}, {-0.00486869, -0.0054067, -0.00583321, -0.00622814, \
-0.00645938, -0.00651717, -0.00562187, -0.00415298, -0.00233435, \
-0.000528968, 0.000858107, 0.00174475, 0.00246199, 0.00260912, 
  0.00232077, 0.00187243, 
  0.00105566}, {-0.00646868, -0.00638845, -0.00656596, -0.00682574, \
-0.00696631, -0.00695649, -0.00597645, -0.00440819, -0.0024844, \
-0.000576321, 0.000883861, 0.00180766, 0.00260912, 0.00279144, 
  0.00248717, 0.00200477, 
  0.00112846}, {-0.00593057, -0.00578386, -0.00591743, -0.00613324, \
-0.00624759, -0.00622976, -0.00534831, -0.00394177, -0.00222045, \
-0.000515071, 0.000787505, 0.00160707, 0.00232077, 0.00248717, 
  0.00221949, 0.00179136, 
  0.00100938}, {-0.0047329, -0.00465564, -0.00478729, -0.00497431, \
-0.00507381, -0.00506182, -0.00434474, -0.00319905, -0.00179844, \
-0.00041328, 0.000642681, 0.00130422, 0.00187243, 0.00200477, 
  0.00179136, 0.00144867, 
  0.000817816}, {-0.0026243, -0.00261327, -0.00270357, -0.00281743, \
-0.00287797, -0.00287265, -0.00246484, -0.00181285, -0.00101669, \
-0.000230905, 0.000366993, 0.000740219, 0.00105566, 0.00112846, 
  0.00100938, 0.000817816, 0.00046254}};


g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 Table[M[[i, 
    j]]/(Plus @@ f[x, y][[i]] Plus @@ 
      f[x, y][[j]]), {i, 1, 17}, {j, 1, 17}]
```

Normal values to test it with, could be: `x = 2`, `y = 300`

The function h[x,y] is a numerical integration, but it was too slow whilst using `NIntegrate`.

This should give me a new 17x17 matrix, which it does, only thing is it takes roughly 35 seconds. In the rest of my calculations the function `g(x,y)` will be used to find a minimum of x and y with `FindMinimum` which will take some time so I want to make this little part as fast as possible. Any ideas how to do it differently which might make it faster? I'm a beginner, so apologies beforehand.

If this is the normal time it takes to do this calculation, I'd appreciate it greatly if you'd let me know too.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe `g[x_, y_] := With[{s=Total[f[x,y],{2}]}, M/Outer[Times,s,s]]`?

Comment: Hard to say anything without examples for `f` and `M`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, sorry for the incomplete question. Hopefully this is better?

Comment: @CarlWoll, wow that worked like a charm thank you very much! Do you have any explanation for why my method clearly isn't the right way of thinking for tackling this computation?

Comment: You're adding up `Plus @@ f[x, y][[i]]` many times over and over again. Carl's `s=Total[f[x,y],{2}]` does it once for all.  That's probably the biggest savings. The `Outer[Times,...]` is similar to `Table[...]`, but `Outer` is optimized for `Times` and machine numbers (for example, on an Intel CPU, it probably takes best advantage of the hardware).

Comment: @MichaelE2 do you have a source for the `Outer` specialization? I'd be interested in reading more on the different functions optimized for numerics and special use cases.

Comment: @b3m2a1 You can test it and see.  That's my evidence.  Also for `Plus` and `List`, IIRC.